# Bug fread in a txt file, read only one time

Tags: php

I'm creating a code to display the name of a server with enterprise rules, So for don't use `Mysql` i try a new things (for me) use php to read and rewrite files, that work perfectly for one part of my code and work perfectly but for the second he only read one time, and when i do a f5 the code don't increment.
He rewrite correctly because my file was at 000 and become 001

I try to use `file()` but he is disable since `7.0`, try to use SplFileObject but it don't want to display anything and i don't like it because i understand nothing when i use it so i come back to `fopen()`,`fread()` and `fwrite()` and that don't work. I'm in`PHP 7.3.1`

The code that works :

```php
<?php 
if ( isset($_POST) AND !empty($_POST) ) {
$nom = "./config.txt";
$filez = fopen($nom, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$i = fread($filez,filesize($nom));
$year = getdate();
$idy = substr($year[year], 2);
$fichier = fopen("./resultsrv.txt", "w") or die("Unable to write file!");
    for ($z; $z<$_POST['nbr']+1 ; $z++) {
        $id =  sprintf("%04d", $i+$z); 
        $nome = $_POST['type'].$_POST['OS'].$idy.$id."<br>" ;
        echo $nome;
        $nomewout = str_replace("<br>", ";", $nome);
        fwrite($fichier,$nomewout);
    }
    $handle = fopen("./config.txt", "w") or die("Unable to write file!");
    fwrite($handle,$id);
    fclose($fichier);
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

and the one that doesn't work because he doesn't increment :

```php
<?php 

if ( isset($_POST) AND !empty($_POST) ) {

    $fileName = 'confchass.txt';
    $read = fopen($fileName,"r");
    $fn = fopen($fileName,"w+");
    $i = fread($read,filesize($fileName));
    $id =  sprintf("%03d", $i+1);

    echo "<div align='center'><h1>Le Chassis</h1>";
    echo $_POST['Marque'].$_POST['DC'].$id;
    echo "</div>";
    fwrite($fn,$id);

    fclose($read);
    fclose($fn);

}
?>
```

I want he output a thing like XXXXXX001 and when i refresh or do a new POST from my forms he output XXXXXX002 and XXXXXX003 .... But he actualy output only XXXXXX001

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php <- it's not disabled?

Comment: A co worker say that for security reason, so even if it's enable I think i can't use it.
But if you have a way to help me with `file()` i take it.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why they consider that a security risk ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you open the file for reading and then for writing.  But from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)...

> 'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the
>   file does not exist, attempt to create it.

So this will blank out the file before you read the value from it.

To fix this (using your current method, you should read the value, then open it for writing and write the new value...

```
$read = fopen($fileName,"r");
$i = fread($read,filesize($fileName));
fclose($read);
$id =  sprintf("%03d", $i+1);

echo "<div align='center'><h1>Le Chassis</h1>";
echo $id;
echo "</div>";
$fn = fopen($fileName,"w+");
fwrite($fn,$id);
fclose($fn);
```

You could shorten this by using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: Thanks that work perfectly !

EDIT : Yes I have forgot it but now that work thanks again